# Ruby on Rails with Apache Web server

Tags: apache-http-server, ruby-on-rails

We have a Ruby on Rails application with Webrick server that uses Apache web server and a php blog for the same ruby website running on the same RHEL server.

I can access the Apache access log and error log for the blog site but I couldn't find any similar access and error log for the Ruby website. I afraid if the Ruby website is not logging anything at this time. How can I get the logs for the Ruby on Rails website else how can I set it to generate access and error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails applications write logfiles in a directory `log/` under the application root. Look there, and you should find the logs you need; their names follow the form `{environment}.log`, where `{environment}` is one of "production", "development", or "test"; this being from the sound of it an app in production, `log/production.log` is the first place to look.